# How can I improve the react performance if I have many text inputs (Hooks) in a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-hooks

## The Problem

I have a form to send data through a api rest in React, the render and the writing on the form is very slow when I have about 80 text fields.

I'm using functional components with hooks to handle the input texts and Material-UI as UI framework.
In a first try, I had a currying function to handle the values:

`setValue = (setter) => (e) => { setter(e.target.value) }`

But the render process was really slow (because I was creating a function in every render), So I send the setter function as a prop,  then it improves a little but not enough.

Actually the input response when I write a key in any input, it's about 500 ms.

**What can I do to get a better performance?**

The code was simplified for understanding purposes.

## Sample code below:

```js
const [input1, setInput1] = useState('')
const [input2, setInput2] = useState('')
const [input3, setInput3] = useState('')
.
.
.
const [input80, setInput80] = useState('')

// render the Inputs
<Input value={input1} setter={setInput1} text="Some label text" />
<Input value={input2} setter={setInput2} text="Some label text" />
<Input value={input3} setter={setInput3} text="Some label text" />
.
.
.
<Input value={input80} setter={setInput80} text="Some label text" />
```

My Input components:

```js
const Input = ({
  value, setter, text, type = 'text'
}) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value: inputValue } = e.target
    setter(inputValue)
  }
  return (
    <Grid>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        type={type}
        label={text}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        multiline={multiline}
      />
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

All input values are must be in a component because I'm need to send them to a server with axios.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the Material-UI Input component is a bit heavy.

I have a [sample codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sun-h3mep) where I initialised around 1000 inputs. Initially it lagged and crashed.

To begin with I added a `memo` to the `Input` component. This memoizes all the `Input` components, triggering a new render only if one of its props has changed.

For a start just add a `memo` to your input component.

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const Input = memo(({
  value, setter, text, type = 'text'
}) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value: inputValue } = e.target
    setter(inputValue)
  }
  return (
    <Grid>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        type={type}
        label={text}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        multiline={multiline}
      />
    </Grid>
  )
})
```

**Note:** If you have a custom setter like in your first case `setValue = (setter) => (e) => { setter(e.target.value) }`, you can wrap that in a `useCallback` to prevent multiple functions to be created for every render.